# Making a class instance variable unwritable from outside world

Tags: ruby, class-instance-variables

```
class Event

    @event_list = {}

    attr_reader :name, :value

    def initialize(name, value)
      @name  = name
      @value = value
    end

    def to_s
      "#{@value}"
    end

    class << self

      def event_list
          @event_list
      end

      def event_list=(value); end

      def register_event(name, value)
          @event_list[name] = Event.new(name, value)
      end

      def registered_events
          event_list
      end
    end
end
```

In the above code snippet I can access @event_list using Event.event_list, interesting thing is I am able to modify this variable from outside

```
Event.event_list[:name] = "hello"
Event.event_list  # => { :name => 'hello' }
```

How can I avoid this ?, I don't want to modify @event_list from outside.

Comment: Don't make an `event_list=` class method?

Comment: this is made to ensure no writing is done to @event_list on doing the assignment

Comment: Sorry, I meant `event_list`. Ultimately if you don't want people to be able to modify it you need to return a copy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't stop outside code from modifying your instance variables in Ruby. Even if you don't use `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` it can still be accessed using `Object#instance_variable_set`. Ruby doesn't have private variables (or constants), only variables that you are politely asked not to modify.

If you don't define `event_list=`, that is seen as an indication that `@event_list` is a private variable. This is the solution to your problem.

Then there is the problem with mutable objects. Since almost all objects in Ruby sadly are mutable, usually if you can just get a reference to an object then you can change it.

This can be solved with `Object#freeze` which stops an object from being modified. Unfortunately this means that not even you can modify it.

Ruby is simply not very good for locking things down. This openness is a core part of the language that you probably need to learn to work with.

Comment: event if I just add *attr_reader :event_list* instead of writing reader and writer methods I can modify the variable. In a class I can make an instance variable unwritable by just using attr_reader, If a class is an object then I should be able to make its instance variable unwriteable.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, just make the methods private:

```
class Event
    @event_list = {a: 'dog'}
    class << self
      def pub_event_list
        @event_list
      end  
      def pub_event_list=(other)
        @event_list=other
      end  
      private
      def event_list
        @event_list
      end
      def event_list=(value)
        @event_list = value
      end
    end
end

Event.event_list
  #=> NoMethodError: private method `event_list' called for Event:Class

Event.pub_event_list
  #=> {:a=>"dog"} 

Event.event_list= {b: 'cat'}
  #=> #NoMethodError: private method `event_list=' called for Event:Class

Event.pub_event_list= {b: 'cat'}
  #=> {:b=>"cat"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `def event_list` on your singleton which is providing access to the variable. Make that method private

EDIT:

When you are declaring `@event_list` it has scope in your singleton methods.

```
class Event
  @event_list = {}

  class << self
    def event_list
      # scoped from above
      @event_list
    end
  end
end

Event.event_list #=> {}
```

To remove access simply make the method private:

```
class Event
  @event_list = {}

  class << self
    private

    def event_list
      # scoped from above
      @event_list
    end
  end
end

Event.event_list #=> NoMethodError: private method `event_list' called for Event:Class
```

Comment: I didn't understand could you please explain a bit?

Comment: @Deepak `event_list` returns the reference. Once you have the reference you can modify it.

Comment: ok, but if I just use attr_reader :event_list then also I can access it and modify it.

Comment: Ah I misread the question. You probably want to make a copy of the data with `deep_clone` or something and return that so the original variable can't be modified

Comment: Even if the reader is made private I need to access the value ourside, the method **registered_events** must return the events outside, freezing seems ok but that means I have to freeze and unfreeze frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I done for now, I don't know if it is a good solution

```
class Event

  @event_list = {}

  attr_reader :name, :value

  def initialize(name, value)
    @name  = name
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@value}"
  end

  class << self
    def register_event(name, value)
      @event_list = @event_list.merge(name => Event.new(name, value))
    end

    def registered_events
      @event_list.freeze
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can access @event_list without letting others to modify.